# Confused about the appropriate design pattern to be used here

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory, builder

I am implementing a class that can download a file from various sources such as ftp, http etc. I started with the following interface

```
class IInternetFileDownloader
{
public:
    IInternetFileDownloader() = default;

    virtual void Download(const std::string& urlToDownloadFrom) = 0;

};
```

I then implemented the classes that will perform the actual download from the appropriate endpoint. So I have a HttpFileDownloader.h as follows

```
#include "IInternetFileDownloader.h"
class HttpFileDownloader : public IInternetFileDownloader
{
public:
    HttpFileDownloader() = default;

    virtual void Download(const std::string& urlToDownloadFrom)
    {
        // download implementation
    }

};
```

So I have a FtpFileDownloader .h as follows

```
#include "IInternetFileDownloader.h"
class FtpFileDownloader : public IInternetFileDownloader
{
public:
    FtpFileDownloader() = default;

    virtual void Download(const std::string& urlToDownloadFrom)
    {
        // download implementation
    }

};
```

I can invoke the appropriate class as below

```
#include "IInternetFileDownloader.h"
#include "HttpFileDownloader.h"

int main()
{
    std::string downloadFromUrl = "http://www.example.org/xyz.zip";
    IInternetFileDownloader* download = new HttpFileDownloader();
    download->Download(downloadFromUrl);
}
```

However, I don't want to instantiate specific HttpFileDownloader or FtpFileDownloader here. In my mind, there should be another class that can just take the url and depending upon the protocol, it can construct the appropriate class. This way the client code (main.cpp) does not need to worry about the instantiation of the appropriate class. I read about the factory and builder design patterns and a little confused about which one will be best to use in this scenario?

Comment: https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/creational_patterns

Comment: your problem statement is good example for `factory method pattern`  because you want to create object without exposing the creation logic to client and the client use the same common interface to create new type of object.

Comment: It seems all you need is a single global function, downloadFile. In the implementation, parse the URL, and depending on protocol portion call another function, either downloadFileHttp or downloadFileFtp. If you only have 2, best way is manually, if you'll have 10, you can use some collection to map from protocol to function pointer. No classes, no factories, and much simpler code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest approach would be to have a static function on IInternetFileDownloader to instantiate the correct subclass.

Also, I don't think you need that default constructors in the base class, but you likely need a default destructor in the base class that is virtual.  That way, your factory function, `CreateDownloader`, that I propose, can return a pointer (or shared_ptr) to an `IInternetFileDownloader` instance that you delete later.

```
class IInternetFileDownloader
{
public:
    virtual ~IInternetFileDownloader() = default;
    virtual void Download(const std::string& urlToDownloadFrom) = 0;

    // parses the url to infer the protocol and construct an instance of a derived class
    static IInternetFileDownloader* CreateDownloader(const std:string& url);
};

class HttpFileDownloader : public HttpFileDownloader 
{
public:
    virtual void Download(const std::string& urlToDownloadFrom) override;
};

class FtpFileDownloader : public IInternetFileDownloader
{
public:
    virtual void Download(const std::string& urlToDownloadFrom) override;
};
```

And that's probably the approach I'd go with.

Another variant of this is that it might make sense to have the "factory" as a separate class. One advantage is that it might enable a better ability to mock an instance of a downloader in a unit test.

```
class IInternetFileDownloader
{
public:
    virtual ~IInternetFileDownloader() = default;
    virtual void Download(const std::string& urlToDownloadFrom) = 0;
};

class InternetFileDownloaderFactory
{
public:
    // parses the url to infer the protocol and construct an instance of a derived class
    virtual IInternetFileDownloader* CreateDownloader(const std:string& url);
};

class InternetFileDownloaderFactoryMock : public InternetFileDownloaderFactory
{
public:
    IInternetFileDownloader* CreateDownloader(const std:string& url) override
    {
         return new MockFileDownloaderFactoryMock();
    }
};

class MockFileDownloaderFactoryMock : public IInternetFileDownloader
{
public:
    virtual void Download(const std::string& urlToDownloadFrom)
    {
       // do nothing or simulate a download
    }
};
```